# How to share remote connection settings across computers? (Netbeans)

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp, dropbox, remote-connection

A friend and I are trying to work together by using dropbox as the synchronization medium right now. We want to have our project be so that when we hit save, our changes are shown on the other's computer, and the changes are also uploaded to a remote server using FTP as well.

Project is set up at: .../Dropbox/Foo/Website

We both access the same project and open it up in netbeans.

A save from one PC updates the other. The problem is that every time one person saves, it messes up the connection setting preferences on the other person's computer. It is a constant tug of war over the personal configuration file.

**Is there a way we can both work together on this? We need very quick synchronization, and we also need to be able to push our content through FTP as well. Preferably with as much automation as possible.**

Solutions I began to try but decided were too annoying (so far):

- On file system save detected, use custom FTP program to sync to ftp server
- On file system sync detected, set project properties file's data to be correct before netbeans FTP upload can begin. (This failed, "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open")
- Manually uploading files using a secondary FTP client like Filezilla.
- Git (Way too many rapid micro changes at this stage of development)

Comment: How would you avoid overwriting each others changes? I would recommend developing locally and use version control to pull / push changes.

Comment: Well, the synchronization would happen often enough for that to not to be a big issue. The Netbeans client would ask, "X file has been updated. Would you like to reload?" If you're working on the file, you could just say no. Eventually, version control will be the way to go for this for sure though, when we leave the rapid prototype phase. For now though, you are right. It may be easier to just run a local php setup and point one of the directories towards the working src folder. Then the remote connection config doesn't need to be changed every time a file is saved in order to test changes.

Comment: To be honest, all I'd really need to do is prevent dropbox from syncing a specific file...